# FloatingActionButton in android is displaying image from src on a blue circle

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I use this floating button:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/floater"
        />
```

Floater is the drawable I want to display. But `FloatingActionButton` is showing its default blue circle and a small image (floater) on it.

Comment: I hope you aren't older as 12.

Comment: @peterh I don't think age matters when you are learning.

Comment: This is why you can always start to learn the proper English grammar. At least start your sentences with a capital case... next time I won't be with you to fix your spelling. I removed my downvote and considering the useful answers I don't initiate a closure of your question. If you learn [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370), it will be here enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FloatingActionButton` acts as you have described: an icon into a colored circle.

It should take `colorAccent` by default.
To change it you can use

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/red"
```

If you want to change icon color instead you can use

```
android:tint="@color/red"
```

Answer (score 0):

please use following dep in gradle.
if studio sdk is 25 then use nigher u can change 25,24,23

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
```